# Footer de WordPress en mitad de la página

Tags: wordpress

me preguntaba si alguien sabría cómo resolver gráficamente con WordPress mi problema. Tengo una página general donde dentro hay otras 4 hojas que conforman toda la información y no sé por qué razón al poner un apartado en borrador y volverlo a publicar el footer y el apartado de contacto se han quedado en mitad de la hoja general. Es decir, no mantiene el orden que debe porque deberían estar abajo. Alguna idea?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Es imposible saber que pasa, sin tener un ejemplo claro de lo que pasa...

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.